# How to get custom extension attributes with microsoft graph api

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to get user details with microsoft-graph

I'm looking for a custom extension element in my response, such as "extension_3a4189d71ad149c6ab5e65ac45bd6add_MyAttribute1"

when I retrieve the response with String, I can see all the elements.

```
final ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange("http://graph.windows.net/tenant.com/me?api-version=1.6, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity(headers),String.class);
```

But when I retrieve the response with com.microsoft.graph.models.extensions.User I can't see the extention anymore.

```
final ResponseEntity<User> response = restTemplate.exchange("http://graph.windows.net/tenant.com/me?api-version=1.6, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity(headers),User.class);
```

How can I retrieve the custom extension in more elegant way than getting in String object and look for elements one by one?

Comment: You can try to create a `User` entity(bean) with all of the fields of the user(including the extension fields), and put this `User` into your code `ResponseEntity<User>` and `User.class`

Comment: Is there another microsoft object that I can use that included this custom extension?
I've tried with $expand=extension, that doesn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because the extension attributes are specific to your tenant, that means its non standard, no out of the box "object class" in the sdk would contain it since it has the app id appended to it. extension_appid_attribname. 
so you would have to handle it yourself. you can try to extend the user class and add a method to read or deserialize/map the json return from the graph api similar to what Hury suggested, or something to that effect. there won't likely be an out of the box solution for this. 
there are also json libraries out there that may help you deserialize to a dynamic object of some sort, if you really didn't want to map the object manually.

**Update:** 
I dug into this a bit further. I don't think its in extensions.extension however, I did find that in the java sdk you can access it . Here's the documentation: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java/wiki/Working-with-Open-Types
You would do something like

```
String ext = 
    user
        .additionalDataManager()
        .get("extension_2lkj3l12jl3j2kj3_yourproperty")
        .getAsString();
```

Give that a try
Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Maybe I miss read the microsoft documentation. I would've have thought this custom extensions are part of their element. Are these types of extensions the same as what the document called "Extension" com.microsoft.graph.models.extensions.Extension

Comment: oh nice.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Please use api
`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users` instead of `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users` api `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users` will return all data with custom data of users.